# Problem with horizontal scrolling in Master-detail table in OAF

Tags: scrollbar, master-detail, oaf

I'm trying to do Master-detail table in OAF project. In my case, I have outer advanced table and inner advanced table(detail). Before adding the details table, the horizontal scroll worked well for the outer table. But now when I hide or show detail table the horizontal scrolling is visible, but does not move. if processResquest method has finished the scroll works well again.

If I remove the detail table, then the horizontal scrolling for the outer table works correctly. I tried to remove the logic from the detail table and left only the header, it didn't help.